# IE8 Select Dropdown list won't display if longer than screen

Tags: html, asp.net, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

A HTML select `drop down list` will not display (the contents) when clicked if the contents extent beyond the bottom of the screen in `IE8`.

`This only happens on the secondary monitors`.

Is there a fix for this or is this a known problem?

Answer (score 1):

We encountered the same problem when the displays are configured with monitor 2 to the side of monitor 1.  If we configure the display position to indicate that monitor 2 is directly above monitor 1, then the drop down list will be displayed on monitor 1 when the main browser window is displayed in monitor 2.

Comment: Yes I have also noticed the same thing. Strange behaviour. @Kurt Schultz